# Simple Encryption/Decryption Program

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I am currently learning how to program in C#. The Chapter which I'm currently on requires me to solve a simple encryption/decryption exercise.

The encryption task goes like this. The user needs to enter a four digit number. My program should then encrypt the number using this algorithm.

```
Example input: 1234

(firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit) % 7,
swap the first and fourth digit and then swap the second and third digit.
```

The encryption part is taken care off. It's pretty straightforward since the algorithm is already given.

My problem lies on the decryption task; the last phase of the decryption algorithm where I have to extract the four digits from their sum. Say 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, how can I extract 1,2,3 and 4 from 10? I don't really know if this is possible, because there are many four digit combination which can produce the number 10 if they are added together. Do you have any ideas how will I be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, as you have identified, this is not reversible, in general.

Comment: `(firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit) % 7,` is not reversible. `swap the first and fourth digit and then swap the second and third digit.` however is. Are you sure the task is not just to do that for encryption?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. The exercise requires me to do a decryption program also.

Comment: If that is the case, maybe the decryption part is just aimed to test my analysis and judgement since its an exercise.

Comment: Can you post a link to the book you're using?

Comment: What's up with the `% 7` part? I mean, once you "encrypt" that with mod 7, there's really no way to get back; way too much loss of information. (unless did you mean _divide_ by 7?)

Comment: Does this apply to all numbers? I mean any number `mod` any number is irreversible?